# JTextField margins

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I want to add margin to a TextField.

Current effect / Desired Effect:

[image: Current Effect]

[image: Desired Effect with 10px left margin]

As you can see, i want to add 10px left margin to JTextField.

Current code:

```
textField_host.setBorder(
    BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
        BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY),
        BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 20, 0, 0 )
    )
);
```

How to achieve that? Thank you.

Comment: Use a layout manager which provides you the means to pad the position, like `GridBagLayout` for example

Comment: Have you tried putting your text field into a `JPanel` with a border? That might be the easiest way to achieve the effect you want. Ideally you achieve alignment with the surrounding components using the parent layout manager.

Comment: Besides, it should `BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outside, inside)`, so it should b something more like `textField_host.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 20, 0, 0 ), textField_host.getBorder()));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, if you have a look at the [JavaDocs for `BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html#createCompoundBorder(javax.swing.border.Border,%20javax.swing.border.Border)) you will see that parameters are in `outside`, `inside` order...

```
public static CompoundBorder createCompoundBorder(Border outsideBorder,
                              Border insideBorder)
```

Which means you should probably be something more like...

```
textField_host.setBorder(
    BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
        BorderFactory.creat‌​eEmptyBorder(0, 20, 0, 0 ), 
        textField_host.getBorder()
    )
);
```

The other solution is to use a layout manager which gives you more control over the layout, like `GridBagLayout`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `Box.createHorizontalStrut(10)` to the left of your textField.